# Adding checked class using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I tried adding checked class to a to do list project using event listeners. But the event listeners are not attaching to every checkbox class. Here's the code

```
export default function (){
    const checkedElements = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox");
    checkedElements.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            element.classList.toggle('checked');
        });
    });
}
```

Here's the website https://joyal-jij0.github.io/todo-list/ & here's the repo https://github.com/joyal-jij0/todo-list.git. try clicking on every checkbox after creating 2-4 to do's. I expected that every checkbox would get the event listener but some are getting and some are getting removed.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor HERE instead of an external site.

Answer (score 2):

1. IDs need to be unique.
2. Use [delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) and relative access via [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
document.getElementById('tasks').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const btn = tgt.closest('button');
  const del = tgt.closest('div.delete');
  const chk = tgt.matches(".checkbox");
  if (btn) {
    if (btn.matches('.save')) {
      console.log('save');
    } else if (btn.matches('.cancel')) {
      console.log('cancel');
    }
  }
  else if (del) {
    tgt.closest('div.task').remove()
  }
  else if (chk) {
    tgt.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
}

i {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.leftContainer {
  background-color: #373c3f;
  height: 100vh;
}

.rightContainer {
  background-color: #2f3437;
  height: 100vh;
}

.projects {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sf-bold sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
  margin: 100px 40px 20px 60px;
}

.project {
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #444a4d;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}

.addProject {
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sf-medium sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 9vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15fr 1fr;
  border-bottom: solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sf-bold sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.task {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .4);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 15fr 15fr 0.1fr;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.addTask {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 50%, .8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checked {
  background-color: #7af76e;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.addToDo {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .4);
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

#textInput {
  background-color: #444a4d;
  border: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

#dateInput {
  background-color: #444a4d;
  border: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 280px;
}

#submit {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #00cd00;
  border: #00cd00;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#cancel {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  border: red;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.task-tem {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .4);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 15fr 0.1fr;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.name {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tasks">

  <div class="task">
    <div class="checkbox"></div>
    <div class="name"> task 1</div>
    <div class="date"></div>
    <div class="delete"><i>✖</i></div>
  </div>


  <div class="task">
    <input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Add Task">
    <input type="date" class="dateInput" placeholder="Add deadline">
    <button class="save">Submit</button>
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="task">
    <input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Add Task">
    <input type="date" class="dateInput" placeholder="Add deadline">
    <button class="save">Submit</button>
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is calling [that `checked` function](https://github.com/joyal-jij0/todo-list/blob/5390044081ea2ba8dcc8d946a79599f2b03ddd36/src/checked.js) from [`addTask`](https://github.com/joyal-jij0/todo-list/blob/5390044081ea2ba8dcc8d946a79599f2b03ddd36/src/addTask.js).

Since the `checked` function internally loops over all checkboxes and adds handlers, they'll have multiple click handlers, and will then toggle the checked state back and forth multiple times. (You could see that if you add a strategic `console.log()` into the handler.)

You can also see those multiple handlers in your browser's inspector's Event Listeners list; this is the first checkbox after I'd added 4 items.

[image]

IOW, you'll only want to add the handler once per new checkbox.

Comment: I strongly suggest delegation rather than a loop

Comment: Sure. There's no loop suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

## Event delegation

You can add the event listener to the parent instead of each element, like that :

```js
const parentCheckbox = document.body
parentCheckbox.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  const element = event.target
  if (element.classList.contains('checkbox')) { // is .checkbox
    element.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
})
```

```css
.checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>checkbox class:</p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="2" />
  <p>not checkbox class:</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="3" />
</body>
```

## Read more:

- [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)
- [Cleaner Code with Event Delegation in JavaScript](https://blog.bitsrc.io/cleaner-code-with-event-delegation-in-javascript-bb6dd27be64d)